# NGINX - https for two domains and letsencrypt

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl

I am a noob when it comes to Linux and nginx, so my question maybe as basic as it
sounds.

So I have two domains domain1.com and domain2.com both pointing to my server. I have obtained a certificate via letsencrypt for each of the two. How can I install each of those for each of the domains?

I have searched the internet and had no luck. So far I came up with this

Config 1:

```
server {
    server_name domain1.com;

    ssl_certificate path/to/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key path/to/cert/key;
}
```

Config two:

```
server {
    server_name domain2.com;

    ssl_certificate path/to/cert2;
    ssl_certificate_key path/to/cert/key2;
}
```

The default config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
}
```

I have created one for both. One doamin was already configured and works fine. But the second can not reach domain2.com via https:// and also the domain points to the default side.

TL;DR How can I use two certificates for two domains on one nginx instance?

Thanks!

EDIT: All other configs are pretty much the basic ones you get with the installation.

Comment: Create a second server block for your second domain?

Comment: Sorry I have two seperate files with the same content the one above is only a sample of wath I did. One file for each domain.

Comment: Then provide all relevant configuration parts for both domains. The given information is not even enough to speculate.

Comment: Sorry I am new. I have edited the post so both configs are present now. Both are located in sites-enabeld and are therefore imported by the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add bindings to each of the server blocks:

```
listen myipaddress:443 ssl http2;
```

The first site is catching the traffic.  You can use the same IP but just need to check that the nginx version supports SNI (should do if a recent version)

Comment: Thank you, when checking the config with nginx -t it tells me that http2 is an invalid parameter. What shall i do?

Comment: Drop out the http2, it's not essential to what you are trying to do, it's just a nice to have.  Should be fine with the rest

Comment: Thank you unfortunately i can not upvote your answer.